# NSJSONSerialization with Swift 2

Tags: json, swift2

```
import UIKit

let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/test.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

// modify the request as necessary, if necessary

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

    if data == nil {
        print("request failed \(error)")
        return
    }

    var parseError: NSError?
    if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? [String: String] {
        if let name = json["name"] {
            print("name = \(name)")   // if everything is good, you'll see "William"
        }
    } else {
        print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("raw response: \(responseString)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

This code worked before the update to Xcode 7 but now there is an error in

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: &parseError) as? [String: String] {
```

Can anyone help me convert it to Swift 2?

Comment: Have a look at my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187781/2227743

Comment: check this too....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815592/nsurl-problems-in-swift/32815630#32815630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/test.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    // modify the request as necessary, if necessary

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if data == nil {
            print("request failed \(error)")
            return
        }

        do{
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: String] {
                if let name = json["name"] {
                    print("name = \(name)")   // if everything is good, you'll see "William"
                }
            } else {
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("raw response: \(responseString)")
            }
        }catch {
            print("bom bom bom error")
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I only have one more problem now, if I put you code into a function and than let the function return a string, I cant manage to get it to return the Name. It prints the name fine but it never lets me put it into a variable, it always tells me that the variable is empty after the task.resume() is executed, why is that ?

Comment: please write a new question and give me the link

Comment: I put it in more detail as "add on" in the question. XD

Comment: You shouldn't put it here. It's a different problem. Kindly create a new one. Nevertheless, I will check your updated question once I get back to my office

Comment: OK, ill send the link in a bit.

Comment: Soory it might take longer because Stack overflow says I make bad questions and now I have to answer a buch. So if you answer it hear I can post the answer underneath the new question when I can make it, or you just answer when I can make questions again.

Comment: @HuRiXD okay, update your question here, include the new problem please

Comment: OK, its everything under add on:

Comment: so basically, your new problem is that you want the `Return` string to have the json["ID"] after the execution finishes, right?

Comment: Yes that it, i just didnt know hot to write it.

Comment: @HuRiXD okay i see yoru problem, actually, you shouldn't do that, because what you are doing is requesting information from a web service, so you shouldn't expect to have the information **directly** after calling the task.resume. so what i did is creating a new outlet (text view) and when you parse your json, i set the `ID` variable, to that outline, like this: ` self.textViewTest.text = ID` and it works.

Comment: So after    'if let ID= json["ID"] {'  i should put    'self.TestTextView.text = ID' ? Or is that now what you meant ?

Comment: @HuRiXD yes inside that `if` you should assign the `ID` to some outlet, I created a textview called TestTextView, and i assigned the value of `ID` to it and it works.

Comment: It gives me the error Thread 4: signal SIGABRT when i do that and crasches the app

Comment: @HuRiXD please put a new question, i can't see the full problem like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414503/get-json-value-after-conection-function-executed

Comment: They close the quesiton while i was writing an answer for, but as i told you, this not synconized call, so you can't expect to get and **read** the `Return` variable **directly** when you call task.resume(). i tried your code and it is really working. just put the result to a text view or a label